# Intersect ignores joined fields

Tags: qgis, intersection, attribute-joins

In QGIS, I use the intersect function provided by the saga algorithms. The resulting shapefile contains the original attributes but misses joined fields of the input layers. Is there an elegant workaround?

Comment: Not really elegant but I think the easiest way to get around this is to save the input shapefile (with the joined fields) as a **new** shapefile and then use this in your intersection tool as most tools tend to ignore joined fields.

Comment: thanks for the comment - indeed, this works. However, its not "elegant" :)
I'd love QGIS to have an option to store joined fields *in* the original shapefile. It can really be annoing to save a new file, delete the original file, rename the new file...

Comment: What version of QGIS and SAGA are you using? Tested this on QGIS 2.18.13 with SAGA 2.3.1 on Linux, and the joined fields were retained after performing "line-polygon intersection" from SAGA.